# Replace <NULL> tag with the newline in java

Tags: java, jira

I wanted to replace **NULL inside <>** with the **\n** i.e. It should go to next line.

I have tried using

```
      String replace_string = str.replaceAll("<NULL>","\n");
```

The output is : It is removing  but the next content of string is not going to next line.

Following is my string : Some text from my string

```
"~|B|    Book Definition ID = NORMAL"+
"~|B|    Side = <NULL>"+
"~|B|    Status = <NULL>"+
"~|B|    Owner ID = <NULL>"+
"~|B|    Session Index = <NULL>"+
"~|B|    Value = <NULL>"+
"~|B|    Time Duration = <NULL>"
```

Can anyone please help me??

Thanks & Regards,

Renu

Comment: You mean it's removing <NULL> but not inserting the newline? or it's inserting the newline, but it has no effect?

Comment: If the new line is having no effect it might be your OS. You could try System.getProperty("line.separator") to get the correct new line for your OS.

Comment: thanks for replying. Actually I can see in my java program but the new line is not inserting in JIRA

Comment: It might be the fact that you're search for <NULL> but your text contains < NULL>.  Spaces matter.

Comment: I have tried using System.getProperty("line.separator") but still no luck. :(

Comment: "It is removing but the next content of string is not going to next line." How did you verify that? Where is the string not goint to the next line?

Answer (score 3):

There are spaces in your tags, is that intentional? If so, use `str.replaceAll("<\\s*NULL>", "\n")`

Comment: Thanks for replying. No, there are no spaces actually i gave because that tag was not getting displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Updated: As per the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), try this instead:

```
String replace_string = str.replaceAll("<NULL>",Matcher.quoteReplacement("\n"));
```

Comment: Hi Stefan, Its not an HTML page, Its a very simple String operation. **\n** is not working for me. I wanted to insert new line.

Comment: What do you mean by _"Actually I can see in my java program but the new line is not inserting in JIRA"_? Where do you see the resulting string? Also note that variable `str` will not be changed after this operation - you need to use `replace_string`.

Comment: yes I am using replace_string only. I can see in the log file as well as when I run my program in java console I can see that <NULL> tag is getting replaced by whitespace not by new line.

Comment: Ok, we should always [check the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) first :) Try this: `str.replaceAll("<NULL>",Matcher.quoteReplacement("\n"));`

Answer (score 0):

I think the whitespaces are the culprit. If you dont know if there is going to be whitespaces in the parts of the string you want to replace, you should consider using RegEx to match the part of the string you want to replace.